# Tax rebate for home loan of under construction property

Tags: taxes, india, tax-deduction, first-time-home-buyer

I am living in a rented house. This year (F.Y. 2016-17) I have booked an apartment in the same city for which I will get the possession after 3.5 years. I have opted for CLP and I am paying the EMI since June 2016.

Now for my case there are 3 components which can be claimed under various scenarios.

1. HRA.
2. Principle repayment done during the year.
3. Interest repayment done during the year.

Could you please help me in understanding on what I can claim out of 3 mentioned above and under what section (I am not in possession of my apartment as it is still under construction)

Also, If possible, what all documents I need to claim the tax exceptions under the 3 categories mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't have the possession of the house, you can only claim rent for this year.

Depending on city, there are rules as to how much rent can be claimed.